# Tool to format lines of text into array

Tags: formatting

I frequently come across this problem. I have a file:

```
something
something2
something3
```

which I want output as:

```
"something","something2","something3"
```

any quick tool for this, preferably online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just a one off thing, it'd be pretty easy to just do it with a search & replace in any advanced-ish text editor...

For example in [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm):

- Do a Replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Search Mode" to "Extended"
- Find: `\r\n`
- Replace with: `","`

(of course you'll need an extra quote at the very start & very end of the file).

If you need to do it more than once, writing a small script/program that did a regular expression replace over the file would be fairly straight forward too.

**Edit**: If you really wanted to do it online, you could use an [online regular expression tester](http://www.regextester.com/) (in this case you want to use `\n` as the regex and `","` as your replace pattern, leaving the other settings alone).

Answer (score 1):

A quick Python hack?

```
lines = open('input.txt').xreadlines()
txt = ','.join(['"%s"' % x for x in lines])
open('output.txt', 'w').write(txt)
```